# JSON on LINQ, dynamic query method

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

Method with variable that accept variety of JSON structure to be query over linq...

Currently my result is heading the right direction returning the select result over the linq query but it's **hard coded**.

I have fews sets of data structure,

example belows:-

```
var SET_A=[
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 4.795,
        "Status": "Poor"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 4.083333,
        "Status": "Fair"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 8.031212,
        "Status": "V.Poor"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 10.6275,
        "Status": "V.Poor"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 3.876363,
        "Status": "Fair"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C019",
        "Growth": 7.735714,
        "Status": "V.Poor"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C020",
        "Growth": 3.196477,
        "Status": "Good"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C020",
        "Growth": 3.2,
        "Status": "Good"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C020",
        "Growth": 4.51125,
        "Status": "Fair"
    },
    {
        "Axel": "C020",
        "Growth": 4.125,
        "Status": "Fair"
    }
];
```

another sample data.

```
var SET_B = [
    {
        "Class": "H",
        "Points": 252.17,
        "TotalAchieve": 252.17,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    },
    {
        "Class": "A",
        "Points": 36.44,
        "TotalAchieve": 36.44,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    },
    {
        "Class": "B",
        "Points": 442.07,
        "TotalAchieve": 442.07,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    },
    {
        "Class": "C",
        "Points": 852.32,
        "TotalAchieve": 852.32,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    },
    {
        "Class": "D",
        "Points": 903.96,
        "TotalAchieve": 1323.83,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    },
    {
        "Class": "E",
        "Points": 0,
        "TotalAchieve": 0,
        "LastRecord": 2011
    },
    {
        "Class": "J",
        "Points": 0,
        "TotalAchieve": 0,
        "LastRecord": 2011
    },
    {
        "Class": "M",
        "Points": 0,
        "TotalAchieve": 0,
        "LastRecord": 2011
    },
    {
        "Class": "T",
        "Points": 0,
        "TotalAchieve": 0,
        "LastRecord": 2011
    },
    {
        "Class": "T",
        "Points": 2486.96,
        "TotalAchieve": 2906.83,
        "LastRecord": 2012
    }
]
```

Possiblity of few more others variant of data in valid JSON structure

my execution ..

```
ExtractSeries(SET_A, "Growth","Status","Axel");
```

or

```
ExtractSeries(SET_B, "Points","Class","LastRecord");
```

OR

```
ExtractSeries(SET_B, "TotalAchieve","Class","LastRecord");
```

I am stuck at this where i am trying

1. to make use of seedA and seedB to be replace at the Select.
2. to make use of the group by in the linq.

   ```
   public List<string> ExtractSeries(string JSONDs, string seedA,string seedB,string groupby)
   {  
       var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       var table = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>JSONDs, 
       dynamic data = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(jss.Serialize(table));

       var result = from x in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)data 
                   select new {
                       *x.Growth*,
                       *x.Status*
                    };
   ```

   }

I am trying to achieve this "kind" of structure

```
[{
    "Name": "C019",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Growth": 4.796,
            "Status": "Poor"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 4.083333,
            "Status": "Fair"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 8.031212,
            "Status": "V.Poor"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 10.6275,
            "Status": "V.Poor"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 3.876363,
            "Status": "Fair"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 7.735714,
            "Status": "V.Poor"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 3.196477,
            "Status": "Good"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 3.2,
            "Status": "Good"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 4.51125,
            "Status": "Fair"
        },
        {
            "Growth": 4.125,
            "Status": "Fair"
        }
    ]
},....more data with same structure above i.e "Name":"C020"
]
```

or

```
[
    {
        "Name": "2012",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Class": "H",
                "Points": 252.17
            },
            {
                "Class": "A",
                "Points": 36.44
            },
            {
                "Class": "B",
                "Points": 442.07
            },
            {
                "Class": "C",
                "Points": 852.32
            },
            {
                "Class": "D",
                "Points": 903.96
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "2011",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Class": "E",
                "Points": 0
            },
            {
                "Class": "J",
                "Points": 0
            },
            {
                "Class": "M",
                "Points": 0
            },
            {
                "Class": "T",
                "Points": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: so do you want return List<string> or List<"SomethingObjectFromJSON">?

Comment: List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.add("{[{"Name": "2012", "Data": [....");   

public class someObjFrJSON{
  public string name{get;set;}
   public List<string> data{get;set;}
}

it be great to have it in List<class> but how do i make a dynamic class when there is variant type of data ... the data part could contain.. string or double or int..

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. I tried to write a converter, but it's hard without having the data to test on. I think you should try deserializing the data to a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` object, and then investigate the `group` clause to produce the output in the format you need. If you can provide C# code containing a string representation of your data, I can help more.

Comment: @Oliver Sorry, I try my bests. 
The mock data to test is the `var SET_A` and `var SET_B`..

Comment: @Oliver here's another sample
string SET_C="{\"Axel\":\"C019\",\"Growth\":4.795,\"Status\":\"Poor\"},{\"Axel\":\"C019\",\"Growth\":7.735714,\"Status\":\"V.Poor\"},{\"Axel\":\"C020\",\"Growth\":3.196477,\"Status\":\"Good\"},{\"Axel\":\"C020\",\"Growth\":3.2,\"Status\":\"Good\"},{\"Axel\":\"C020\",\"Growth\":4.51125,\"Status\":\"Fair\"},{\"Axel\":\"C020\",\"Growth\":4.125,\"Status\":\"Fair\"}"; 
List<string> xList = new List<string>(); 
xList  = ExtractSeries(SET_C, "Growth","Status","Axel");

Comment: @SiGaban, are you try sample code in my answer? it waht you want or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
private static List<SomeClass> ExtractSeries(string JSONDs, string seedA,string seedB,string groupby)
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return (from item in jss.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(JSONDs)
            select new { val = new Dictionary<string, object>(){{ seedA, item[seedA]}, {seedB, item[seedB] }}, groupKey = item[groupby] } into sampleObj
            group sampleObj by sampleObj.groupKey into g
            select new SomeClass{ Name = g.Key, Data = g.Select(i=>i.val).ToList() })
           .ToList();
}
```

if you serialize this with `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ExtractSeries(SET_B, "Points","Class","LastRecord"))` as result you get string as expected

where `SomeClass`like this

```
public class SomeClass{
    public string Name;
    public List<Dictionary<string,object>> Data;
}
```

Comment: This is it. Efficient.. now i can reuse this code again and again.. Thank You! Happy Holiday!